# Passing variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var urlquery = location.href;
   var urlparts = urlquery.split('='); 
   var urlplan  = (urlparts[1]);      

   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#LDF a').click(function() {  
         $.ajax({
            url: 'src/ldf_dpd_list.php?search-n=urlplan',
            success: function (data) {
               $('#dpd').html(data);
            }
         });
      });
   });
```

Hi I am new to javascript and Ajax and trying to pass the variable urlplan, what is the correct way to pass the variable.

Comment: Are you trying to bold that variable or is your code like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the following should do it:

```
var urlparts = urlquery.split('='); 
var urlplan  = urlparts[1];

// ...

$.ajax({
   url: 'src/ldf_dpd_list.php?search-n=' + urlplan,
   success: function (data) {
      // ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "src/ldf_dpd_list.php?search-n="+urlplan,
```

for more than one variable

```
url: "src/ldf_dpd_list.php?search-n="+urlplan+"&amp;xyz="+variablName,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from my easyXDM library

```
var _query = (function(){
    var query = {}, pair, search = location.search.substring(1).split("&"), i = search.length;
    while (i--) {
        pair = search[i].split("=");
        query[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    return query;
}());
```

Use it like this

```
alert(_query["urlplan"]);
```

or

```
alert(_query.urlplan);
```